# Extract all links from a string with google app script

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

i have an string variable with links inside (among other text), and i want to be able to extract all links containing a certain patron (like containing the word 'case')... is this possible to do?

Variable string is something like:

```
var string = 'here is some text line among the ones there will be links like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725199/extract-all-links-from-a-string-with-google-app-script?noredirect=1#comment68679843_40725199 and more';
```

As a workaround, i used what described here: [extract links from document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727341/get-all-links-in-a-document#), to create a document with the string as content and then extract the links, but i would like to do it directly...

Regards,

EDIT (To Ruben):

If i use:

```
var string = 'http://mangafox.me/manga/tales_of_demons_and_gods/c105/1.html here is some text line among the ones there will be links like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725199/extract-all-links-from-a-string-with-google-app-script?noredirect=1#comment68679843_40725199 and more ';
```

I got only the first link twice (see screenshot [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14114808/Captura1.JPG)).

And if i use:

```
var string = 'here is some text line among the ones there will be links like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725199/extract-all-links-from-a-string-with-google-app-script?noredirect=1#comment68679843_40725199 and more http://mangafox.me/manga/tales_of_demons_and_gods/c105/1.html ';
```

The same again (see screenshoot [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14114808/Captura.JPG)).

Comment: What do you mean by "an string variable with links inside"? Are they URL? Including a sample string could clarify what you mean. What do you tried?

Comment: ok. variable string is something like:

    var string = 'here is some text line among the ones there will be links like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725199/extract-all-links-from-a-string-with-google-app-script?noredirect=1#comment68679843_40725199 and more';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Google Apps Script

```
function test2(){
  var re = /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'"".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/i;
  var string = 'here is some text line among the ones there will be links like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725199/extract-all-links-from-a-string-with-google-app-script?noredirect=1#comment68679843_40725199 and more';
  for(var i = 0; i <= re.exec(string).length; i++){
    if(re.exec(string)[i]) Logger.log(re.exec(string)[i]) 
  }
}
```

## JavaScript.

```js
var re = /\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'"".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/i;
var string = 'here is some text line among the ones there will be links like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725199/extract-all-links-from-a-string-with-google-app-script?noredirect=1#comment68679843_40725199 and more here is some text line among the ones there will be links like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725199/extract-all-links-from-a-string-with-google-app-script?noredirect=1#comment68679843_40725199 and more';
for(var i = 0; i <= re.exec(string).length; i++){
  if(re.exec(string)[i]) console.log(re.exec(string)[i])
}
```

## Reference

[RegularExpression to Extract Url For Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957149/regularexpression-to-extract-url-for-javascript)

Comment: Ok, I used your updated version on this string:

'http://mangafox.me/manga/tales_of_demons_and_gods/c105/1.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725199/extract-all-links-from-a-string-with-google-app-script/40728530?noredirect=1#comment68918084_40728530 here is some text line among the ones there will be links like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40725199/extract-all-links-from-a-string-with-google-app-script?noredirect=1#comment68679843_40725199 and more http://mangafox.me/manga/tales_of_demons_and_gods/c105/1.html';

Comment: I have the same problem with only getting the first link. Any progress during the last 4 years, @Rubén? :-)

Comment: @BjörnLarsson The code in this answers is working correctly. Please post a new question including a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

If you're only getting the first match then I think you need the 'g' flag on the Regular Expression to capture all matches, then each call to exec() will return the next match. I'm using:

```
const re = /(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.])*(?:\([-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*\)|[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])/igm;

while ((reResults = re.exec(s)) !== null) { //finds next match
      Logger.log(reResults[0]); //result of next match
}
```